# What is the definition of natural numbers according to Category Theory?

Tags: category-theory, natural-numbers

Can someone explain to me the definition of natural numbers in Category Theory in an easy-to-understand language with little to no prior knowledge of the theory if at all possible?

I checked this [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_numbers_object) page but unfortunately couldn't understand.

Comment: What part of this wikipedia definition didn't you understand?

Comment: @NoelLundström Most of it unfortunately

Comment: What do you mean by "in category theory"?  Normally, the definition used in category theory is the same as the definition used in the rest of mathematics...

Comment: In particular, the notion of a "natural numbers object" that you link to is very different from "the definition of natural numbers according to category theory".  Instead, it is a *generalization* of the natural numbers.

Comment: @EricWofsey what I mean is.. for example .. in set theory natural numbers are defined in terms of sets .. that’s because set theory is considered a foundations to mathematics.. and as category theory is an alternate foundations .. I thought there might be a definition for them specific to category theory .. so that’s my question

Comment: Category theory is emphatically **not** an alternate foundation to mathematics in the same sense that set theory is.  There are some alternate foundations which use ideas from category theory but that "category theory" itself is not one and in any case you would need to specify exactly what alternate foundation you are talking about.

Comment: @EricWofsey I think you'll have to forgive readers for disagreeing if they have read this Mac Lane quote: *"We have described a category in terms of sets, as a set of objects and a set of arrows. However, categories can be described directly - and they can then be used as a possible foundation for all of mathematics, thus replacing the use in such a foundation of the usual Zermelo-Fraenkel axioms for set theory."* (The intro paragraph to the *Foundations* Appendix of Categories for the working mathematician.)

Comment: @EricWofsey I'm not trying to argue from authority, I'm just saying that many (including myself) are going to be under the impression having heard it - in no uncertain terms - from 'the bible'.  Maybe it's worth explaining if there are further qualifications to make.

Comment: Tom Leinster also seems to also put "categorical set theory" on equal footing with ZFC in Chapter 3.3 of *Basic category theory*.

Comment: @rschwieb: Those are allusions to (two different!) "alternate foundations which use ideas from category theory" that I mentioned before.  Neither one is actually very commonly used as a foundation (even by most people who do category theory).  Conflating them with just "category theory" is misleading since the vast majority of study of category theory is completely orthogonal to this choice of foundations and leads to lots of confused students who think that somehow they aren't allowed to use their familiar foundation for math when studying categories.

Comment: @EricWofsey I think I agree with that much.  Maybe "How does one define the natural numbers in 'categorical set theory'?" is a charitable reading, but it's worth mentioning that calling it 'category theory' won't do in most cases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\require{AMScd}$You can define natural numbers as follows (or in a similar programming language that supports the same structures you need; I'm using Haskell because this comes from a lecture I gave):

```
data N = Z
       | Suc N
       deriving (Eq, Show)
```

You don't have to really understand what's going on, if you are not familiar with Haskell. This is just the way you tell Haskell that a new data type, called `N` contains terms ("elements") of two possible kinds: either `Z` (zero, of course), or an element of the form `Suc n` for another $n\in \mathbb N$.

This defines the type of natural numbers: there is nothing else inside $\mathbb N$ other than $0,1=Suc\; 0,2=Suc\; (Suc\; 0),\dots$; from this it follows basically everything you know about the natural numbers. For example, the `plus` function can be defined "by induction", because in order to define `n m +` you only have to tell me what is `0 m +` and what is `(Suc n) m +`; all else follows. So:

```
plus :: N -> N -> N
plus Z n = n -- 0 + n = n, for all n
plus (Suc m) n = Suc (plus m n) -- (1 + m) + n = 1 + (m + n), for all m,n
```

This works: for example, `1 1 + = 2`:

```
Prelude> (Suc Z) `plus` (Suc Z)
      => Suc (Suc Z)
```

So far so good. We can define things using induction. But what happened *exactly*? Category theory is helpful to understand it.

Define a category $\textsf{Dyn}$ whose objects are triples $(X, t : X \to X,x : X)$, i.e. diagrams
$$
\begin{CD}
  1 @>>x>  X @>>t>  X
\end{CD}
$$
and morphisms between $(X,t,x)$ and $(Y,g,y)$ consist of functions $u : X \to Y$ such that $u(x)=y$ and $u\circ t=g\circ u$, i.e. of commutative diagrams
$$
\begin{CD}
  1 @>>x> X @>>t> X \\
    @| @VuVV @VVuV \\
  1 @>>y> Y @>>g> Y
\end{CD}
$$
The object $\mathbf{N}=(\mathbb{N}, \text{s} : \mathbb N \to \mathbb N, 0 : \mathbb N)$, or rather the type `N` of the type declaration above, belongs to this category if we let $\text{s}$ be the function `Suc :: N -> N` sending a natural number to its successor.

Let $\mathbf{X} = (X,t,x)$ be any object of $\sf Dyn$; then, there is an arrow $u : \mathbf N \to\mathbf X$ in $\sf Dyn$ such that
$$
\begin{CD}
 1  @>>z>   \mathbb N @>>>   \mathbb N  \\
@| @VuVV @VVuV \\
 1 @>>x>  X @>>t>  X
\end{CD}
$$
This means that given an initial value $u(0)=x$ and any endomorphism of the set $X$, there is a unique possible way to define a sequence of element $u(n)$ of $X$ recursively, by setting $u(0) = x$ and $u(n+1) = t(u(n))$.

Moreover, such a function $u$ is *unique* with respect to this property; if there is another sequence $v : \mathbb N \to X$ with the same property, the equality of $u,v$ can be assessed ``by induction'' using $t$: $u(0)=v(0)=x$, and $u(n+1)=t(u(n))=t(v_n)=v(n+1)$. This means precisely that $\bf N$ is an *initial object* of the category $\textsf{Dyn}$.

The category $\sf Dyn$ models the notion of a *discrete dynamical system*: a set $X$ and an initial state $x : X$ are given, together with a function $t : X \to X$ mapping *evolution* of the system in discrete time, according to the function $t$.

This universal property amounts exactly to the request you see in the Wikipedia page.